# Unity video player component URL link to file on a device

Tags: android, url, unity-game-engine, video

This might sound like a dumb question to some (it sort of does to me) but I cant seem to get a successful Unity video player URL link to a video file on an Android. I am sure there is just something really simple i'm missing. I have little experience developing for mobile so I'm not even sure what the "correct way" to set up a file path is. Also when I attempt to drag and drop the file from the Android device opened in windows file explorer Unity rejects it, I am assuming this is because its smart enough to realize that it is not the correct path.

The same video will successfully link on a computer via standard file path "/users/name/desktop/video.mp4".

Comment: Could you please add more detail.

Comment: Ok so the scenario is I am using the Unity video player component to play a video that is on an Android device. I am linking this video via URL as it is a large file. The problem is Unity cannot seem to find the video due to what I can only assume is the file path locating it.

Comment: Where is the file located, in an external or internal storage?

Comment: When you don't add your code to your question, it shows that you are expecting people to write code for you instead of helping to fix your code. The answer from the duplicate shows how to play video from a local path/assetbundle.

Comment: this file path if the video was on a PC would be something like "/users/name/desktop/video.mp4" (this works). If I do the same thing with the video on an Android device , something like " /root/SD card/Videos/video.mp4" It cant locate the video. Now I have no idea if that is even anywhere near the correct way to establish a file path on an Android device, As I stated above I have very little experience with Android development and no documentation I have found so far has helped me with this issue.

Comment: An SD card. would that be the issue?